# silverlight MVVM retrieve datagrid selected rows on radioBox selection

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I have a dialogBox populates Grid Row , i want to selected particular Grid Row data on radio Button selection in ViewModel

Here is my Xaml

```
<cc:DialogBase xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="LMS.Client.View.CampaignSearchResultsDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.View;assembly=LMS.Client.Common"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
    xmlns:attach="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Model.ViewModels.AttachedProperties;assembly=LMS.Client.Model"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Model.ViewModels.Converters;assembly=LMS.Client.Model"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Model;assembly=LMS.Client.Common">
    <cc:DialogBase.Resources>
        <converter:DataContextFinderFromControl x:Key="dataContextFinder"/>
        <model:ViewModelSource Source="{Binding}" x:Name="viewModel"/>
    </cc:DialogBase.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="300" Width="600">

        <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Leads}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedLead,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="dgSearchResult"
                    Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <RadioButton Content="Test" Style="{StaticResource SemiRadioButtonStyle}" GroupName="Lead"
                                         IsEnabled="True" Command="{Binding Path= CheckedCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding InboundChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>


        </sdk:DataGrid>

        <StackPanel Width="300" Height="50" Background="White">
            <Grid Height="50">

            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</cc:DialogBase>
```

and the ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using LMS.Server.DataAccess;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using LMS.Client.Commanding;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LMS.Client.Model
{
    public class CampaignSearchResultsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public CampaignSearchResultsViewModel(List<Lead> obj)
        {
            foreach(Lead lead in obj)
            {
                SelectedLead = lead;
            }
        }

        public CampaignSearchResultsViewModel()
        {

            this.Commands.Add("CheckedCommand", new ActionCommand<Lead>(CheckIt));

            _leads = new ObservableCollection<Lead>();
            // this.icv=System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.SourceProperty(_leads);
            //_leads.Add(new Lead { FirstName = "Neeraj", LastName = "Verma" });
            //_leads.Add(new Lead { FirstName = "Tarun", LastName = "Singh" });
        }


        private void CheckIt(Lead lead)
        {
            SelectedLead = lead;
            LeadViewModel lmv = new LeadViewModel(this);

            var x = SelectedLead;
            CampaignSearchResultsViewModel vm = new CampaignSearchResultsViewModel();

        }



        #region Private
        private ObservableCollection<Lead> _leads;

        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

        private ICommand _checkedCommand;
        private object _testProperty;

        private Lead _selectedLead;

        private ICollectionView icv;

        #endregion

        private ICommand _checkedRadioCommand;
        private bool _inboundChecked;


        #region Properties
        public ObservableCollection<Lead> Leads
        {
            get { return _leads; }
            set
            {
                _leads = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("Leads");
            }
        }

        public Lead SelectedLead
        {
            get { return _selectedLead; }
            set { _selectedLead = value; }
        }

        public ICommand CheckedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return Commands["CheckedCommand"];
            }
        }

        public bool InboundChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return _inboundChecked;
            }
            private set
            {
                if (_inboundChecked != value)
                {
                    _inboundChecked = value;
                    FirePropertyChanged("InboundChecked");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I cant able to map data in the Grid on radio Button, Please tell me  where I am missing

Answer (score 0):

Add CommandParameter="{Binding}" so that you can get whole object (Lead) in your case in view model. Then you can set this object as selected item. So you can modify your code like

```
 <RadioButton Content="Test" Style="{StaticResource SemiRadioButtonStyle}" GroupName="Lead"
                                     IsEnabled="True" Command="{Binding Path= CheckedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding InboundChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

then in your code you can cast your CommandParameter as Lead and set this object as SelectedLead

Comment: Are you able to retrieve command parameter through command binding??

Comment: i Didnot get your point , if i put debugger , I could not get it on the method .. please contact me skype if you can help me,my id is bs24neeraj , it is urgent , i have to the submit code today